# Was Mirajane born with Satan Soul?

Tags: fairy-tail

Just wondering on this but, was Mirajane born with the certain Take Over ability Satan Soul and how did she learn to master it? Also was Elf-Man and Lisanna born with their abilities too? I was wondering this when I noticed that she can change into not one but two other different forms of Satan's Soul including...

> Satan Soul Sitiri and Satan Soul Halphas as below.

[image: Satan Soul Halphas] [image: Satan Soul Sitiri]

I would like to know if this is revealed in any of the Anime's or Mangas

Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One needs to possess the Demon Factor to use Satan Soul. Mira said it herself:

[image]

It hasn't been explained if she already has it since birth or not.

Comment: Take Over would make sense as being genetic as Elf-Man couldn't control his, it would be weird to learn something in the middle of a job that you couldn't control, though i think Mirajane's family is born with one and learn the rest over time

Comment: @Memor-X Like I said, it's genetic for them, just like you born with music skill or athletic skill, they choose what the best for them. After all, some magic is hard to control if they don't have any experience. Elf-Man only can use part of his body when he take-over for the first time, while Mirajane already master it at her young age.

Comment: Does this mean that you can learn any type of magic?

Comment: @MiharuDante it is possible, some magic can learn by many people, like three Great Magic of Fairy Tail. As long as you are Fairy Tail member, you can learn it. Makarov can create fire although his signature Magic is enlarge his body to gigantic proportions.

Comment: @MiharuDante I've revise my whole answer, I haven't reach this chapter before

Comment: Whats the demon factor? Is it like a metaphor or like quite literally something you need to have Satans Soul or to use it?

Comment: @MiharuDante to answer that question, will spoil latest chapter, you sure you want an answer?

Comment: Nah, im alright. Just couldn't find it when I googled, that's all. : )

Comment: While I think that genetics may have helped, we can see that if you are one of the 10% who can naturally use magic, you can choose whatever you want, just like how Sho, Milliana, or Wally was able to choose their magic, and how Makarov was able to use multiple magics at once (Titan, Light...).  So I feel like no, Mira, Elfman, and Lisanna all chose Take Over magic.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Um, during a battle with Seilah she remembers a time when her, Elfman, and Lisanna were kids. Mirajane saved her town and defeated the demon at church, somehow, she managed to capture its power (her arm was a different form) and the town forced them to leave. Mirajane later bumps into Markarov in Fairytail and explains her takeover power and he convinces her to join the guild, and Elfman and Lisanna learn take over (beast and animal) so she won't feel lonely.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mirijane was born with it but not Elfman and Lisanna because in the anime they said that the people in Fairy tale helped them learn magic

Answer (score -1):

I heard that Mirajane beat a demon (Satan) and she get this power and Elfman and lisanna study this magic because Mira was lonely